# How to add dynamic content in title and meta description in wordpress theme for homepage, post page, category, tag and pages

Tags: post-meta, homepage, frontpage, get-the-title, bloginfo

I am creating wordpress theme and want to get and display dynamic content for my theme Title Tag and Meta Description Tag.

For Title Tag Content: I want Title
For Meta Description: I want Bloginfo('description');

When I used following codes for my title it works fine:

```
<?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ): ?>
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); echo ' | '; bloginfo('description'); ?></title>
    <?php elseif ( is_single() || is_page() ): ?>
    <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <?php elseif ( is_category() ): ?>
    <title><?php single_cat_title(); echo ' | '; bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <?php elseif ( is_tag() ): ?>
    <title><?php single_tag_title(); echo ' | '; bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <?php elseif ( is_day() ): ?>
    <title><?php echo 'Post for the day ' . get_the_date('j F, Y') . ' | '; bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <?php elseif ( is_month() ): ?>
    <title><?php echo 'Post for the month ' . get_the_date('F Y') . ' | '; bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <?php elseif ( is_year() ): ?>
    <title><?php echo 'Post for the year ' . get_the_date('Y') . ' | '; bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But I am trying to make this same code in neat manner something like that:

```
<title>
        <?php
            if( is_home || is_front_page() ): bloginfo('name'); echo ' | '; bloginfo('description');
            elseif( is_single() || is_page() ): wp_title('|', true, 'right'); bloginfo('name');
            elseif( is_category() ): single_cat_title(); echo ' | '; bloginfo('name');
            elseif( is_tag() ): single_tag_title(); echo ' | '; bloginfo('name');
            elseif( is_day() ): echo 'Post for the day ' . get_the_date('j F, Y') . ' | '; bloginfo('name');
            elseif( is_month() ): echo 'Post for the month ' . get_the_date('F Y') . ' | '; bloginfo('name');
            elseif( is_year() ): echo 'Post for the year ' . get_the_date('Y') . ' | '; bloginfo('name');
            endif;
        ?>
    </title>
```

Kindly, tell where I am wrong.

Q2. When I tried to display bloginfo description it is not working. Notice that I am using static front-page for my theme. Those codes are as follow:

```
<?php if (is_single() || is_page()): if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>" />
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php elseif ( is_home() || is_front_page() ): ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Kindly, Show me right way for Dynamic Title and Meta Description for my all post, pages, categories, tags and other pages.

Comment: It found now is online right now. I'll wait for answer till tomorrow evening. Plz, show me right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use WordPress conditionals to determine which page you're on, build the title based on that, then print the title.

```
<?php
  $sep = ' | ';
  $name = get_bloginfo( 'name' );

  if( is_home() || is_front_page() )
    $title = $name . $sep . get_bloginfo( 'description' );

  if( is_single() || is_page() )
    $title = wp_title( $sep, false, 'right' ) . $name;

  if( is_category() )
    $title = single_cat_title( '', false ) . $sep . $name;

  if( is_day() )
    $title = 'Post for the day ' . get_the_date( 'j F, Y' ). $sep . $name;

  if( is_month() )
    $title = 'Post for the month ' . get_the_date( 'F, Y' ). $sep . $name;

  if( is_year() )
    $title = 'Post for the year ' . get_the_date( 'Y' ). $sep . $name;
?>
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
```

Comment: Can you tell me answer to my Q2 i.e. how can I make my custom dynamic description and what is wrong in my code. Thanks for answer for title tag.

Comment: Please, tell me solution for dynamic description related codes too I am waiting for your response

Comment: I used same method to description it worked for all pages but still not working for static home page i.e. front-page. I used codes as: $page_description = get_bloginfo('description'); Plz, give me your valuable suggestion as per your convenient.

Comment: In my case, I've made a diferent `header.php` to the front page, and another `header-inner.php` to the inner pages...